# Regex issue with nested groups and using "^" and "$" in the pattern

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a content like this:

```
var testInput =
    "05(testcontent)\r\n" +
    "06(testcontent2)\r\n" +
    "07(testcontent3)(testcontent4)" +
    "08(testcontent5)";
```

I need to get the one code string and two value strings for each line.
For the first line:

- Code: `"05"`
- Value1: `"testcontent"`
- Value2: Empty string.

For the third line:

- Code: `"07"`
- Value1: `"testcontent3"`
- Value2: `"testcontent4"`

The pattern I use:

```
// (?<Code>[0-9]{2}) - 2 digit number
// \((?<Value1>.+)\) - First value, which is inside the parentheses.
// (\((?<Value2>.+)\))? - Second value, which also is inside the parentheses.
// The second value does not always exist. Which is why it has "?" at its end.
var testPattern = @"(?<Code>[0-9]{2})\((?<Value1>.+)\)(\((?<Value2>.+)\))?";
```

The code I use:

```
var testRegex = new Regex(testPattern,
    RegexOptions.Compiled |
    RegexOptions.CultureInvariant |
    RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture |
    RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach (Match match in testRegex.Matches(testInput))
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1} | {2}",
        match.Groups["Code"].Value,
        match.Groups["Value1"].Value,
        match.Groups["Value2"].Value);
```

The result I get:

```
05: testcontent |
06: testcontent2 |
07: testcontent3)(testcontent4)08(testcontent5 |
```

If I use `^` at the start and `$` at the end of the pattern, I get even worse:

```
07: testcontent3)(testcontent4)08(testcontent5 |
```

So,

- Why does the `^` and `$` complicate things even more when I specified "RegexOptions.Multiline"?
- What is wrong with my pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you ever have closing parentheses inside your Value1 or Value2? If not, I'd suggest using a negated character class like `[^)]+` instead of `.+`. The reason is that `.+` being "greedy" (i.e. repeating as many times as possible) is causing problems in this case.

Comment: Quick question: `[^)]+` means "at least one character which is not `)`". How can I specify "at least one character which is not `(` or `)`"?

Comment: You can add all the characters you want inside the negated character class, like this `[^()]`. That means "exactly one character which is not `(` or `)`". Adding the `+` after that you get "at least one character".

Comment: Oh, so `^` applies to the whole class, not the one character. Thanks again and +1.